# How to add to the paths "index.html"

Tags: php

How can I add `index` to the path, if it's doesn't chose the file already? I mean that if user enters `to/this/page`, it'll change it to `to/this/page/index.html` or to `to/this/page/index.php` if `index.php` doesn't exists. If both `index.php` and the `index.html` dosn't exists, I want it to echo `error`.

Here is what I tried:

```
        if(!file_exists($filename)) {
            if(strpos($filename, ".") === false){
                $nfilename = $filename . "index.html";
                if(!file_exists($nfilename)){
                    $filename .= "index.php";
                    if(!file_exists($filename)){
                        echo 'error';
                    }
                } else $filename = $nfilename;
            } else {
                echo 'error';
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's your end goal here?

Comment: @amphetamachine because it's already being redirected. It shows a PHP page that checks the cookies and if the user allowed to, it shows him the content of the page (by getting the data from the path).

Comment: @amphetamachine The PHP file needs to show the content of the file in the given path. But when the given path isn't ends with a file, only with folder, it can't find the file.

Comment: Are you sure you need PHP? Redirecting from `.../dir/` to `.../dir/index.php` is usually handled by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the request uri have index.php or index.html with this piece of code:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php') === false
    || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.html') === false) {
    // redirect to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] plus one of the index
}
```

Check the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php) array for more info

Comment: Just change the ``$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`` to your variable that contains the path you want to check

Comment: How does it helps me? what if the path ends with `post.php`? It'll return true as well as if it won't end with any file.